# What is the difference between UDP and HTTP torrent trackers?

Tags: http, bittorrent, udp

In the context of bittorrent what's the difference between http and udp trackers? HTTP is an application layer protocol and UDP is a transport layer protocol so the concepts seem non-overlapping. I found [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_tracker) but it doesn't say why UDP is faster than HTTP, this doesn't make sense because HTTP could happen over UDP.

Answer (score 2):

UDP announcement - as far as I know - requires one single packet up and one down. No persistent connection is negotiated or established. The sever does not have to remember which ip:port the announcement came from, only for the brief moment it decides what to answer.

HTTP announcement, however, works over a TCP connection. This means that the connection needs to be negotiated, used and then torn down. All these steps require more than two packets:
  - Negotiation: one SYN up, a SYN-ACK down and an ACK up.
  - Usage. If we're lucky, the HTTP request fits into a single upstream packet. The server then replies with an ACK packet, then sends its response in a separate packet. The client then also replies with an ACK packet. Of course, since it's not the client that dictates how the TCP stream is split into packets but the OS, both the request and the answer may be fragmented into multiple packets, each requiring an ACK in response. Also, other complications such as MTU overruns can force both the server and the client to resend these packets fragmented into smaller sizes.
  - Tearing the connection down also takes three packets: FIN, FIN-ACK and ACK.

So, HTTP announcements require 10 packets at the very least, but potentially more than this, plus some waiting if the network decides to drop a package. For all of this time the server (and the client too, but it doesn't really matter for the client, it's not the one having to deal with upwards from a thousand announcements per second) has to keep the details of the connection in RAM. For a the amount of announcements a single client does the difference is negligible (even light browsing generates more traffic), but at the server side it adds up to amounts where an 5-fold decrease means a lot.

Comment: "UDP announcement - as far as I know - requires one single packet up and one down." That is wrong. If that was true, a tracker could be used as DOS-attack amplifier. A peer must get a connection_id from the tracker before it can make an announce. "HTTP announcements require 10 packets at the very least" A HTTP announce can be made with only five packets total and all packets almost always fits within MTU.