# Proxy Socks5 and allowing UDP trackers connection?

Tags: networking, proxy, bittorrent

OS : Debian 10

Software :Tixati 2.66

Hey hi guys so lately i had some trouble with my torrent client software (stalled)
so i changed for tixati , im a Ipvanish member and so for torrentting i use a socks5

but in Tixati (maybe elsewhere too) their is a warning phrase under the proxy box:

```
IMPORTANT:
SOCKS/HTTP proxy servers only support outgoing TCT connections.
Incoming connections and UDP will not be affected by these settings. 
You should turn off DHT and disable UDP peer and trackers connections 
if you are using a SOCKS/HTTP proxy to conceal your true IP adress.
```

the issue here is that almost all trackers uses UDP tracker instead of http ones and from what i understand Http needs way more condition and can so fail to start (which happens pretty often on old torrent with not much peers)

i did read this [What is the difference between UDP and HTTP torrent trackers?](https://superuser.com/questions/843110/what-is-the-difference-between-udp-and-http-torrent-trackers) to get those informations

so my questions are gonna be pretty straight ;

Is my ISP able to know :

-what i do using a Socks5 (torrenting) (tracking me)

-what i do if i use a socks5 and have UDP tracker connection enable ?

i mean am i giving them a stick to hit me with by enabling UDP trackers connections ?

So far without knowing those answers im just disabling UDP trackers connections but if i can still use em it'll be way better (lol)

thanks in advance